# Easiest way to setup Ubuntu as a VPN server

Tags: vpn

I know there are many tutorials on the net for setting up VPN client and server.

I you find one that is **simple/short**, I am interested only in the server part.

For client, I will use OS X so I prefer a solution that uses `L2TP over IPsec` or `PPTP` because I suppose Cisco IPsec would cost something.

I don't want to spent too many hours setting it up. You know, maybe someone already made a setup script :)

Note: I am using an EC2 micro instance running Ubuntu 12.04 on it.

Comment: Note: CISCO IPSec can be achieved via StrongSwan and a lot of configuration, but it's tricky.  PPTP is not secure anymore.  ANd L2TP over IPSec requires both L2TP and IPSec configuration.  Pick at your leisure, although my answer explains PPTP

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As of Sierra, macOS no longer supports PPTP vpn. This answer is not valid for macOS clients Sierra and beyond.

PPTP via PoPToP is easy

1. `apt-get install pptpd`
2. edit `/etc/pptpd.conf` and set the remoteip option to a range on your network that is NOT served by your DHCP server.
3. edit `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` and add a username and password

e.g.

```
vpnuser pptpd vpnpassword *
```

This is all it takes to setup pptp. Now test it with your OS X client.

Comment: I'm also wondering which localip and remoteip values are the safest, considering that I'm going to connect to this server from any location. Definetly the default values with `192.168.0.` and `192.168.1.` are probably one of the worst possible.

Comment: May 12 13:28:06 zork pppd[9447]: Plugin /usr/lib/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
May 12 13:28:06 zork pppd[9447]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
May 12 13:28:06 zork pppd[9447]: Using interface ppp0
May 12 13:28:06 zork pppd[9447]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
May 12 13:28:36 zork pppd[9447]: Hangup (SIGHUP)
May 12 13:28:36 zork pppd[9447]: Modem hangup
May 12 13:28:36 zork pppd[9447]: Connection terminated.
May 12 13:28:36 zork pppd[9447]: Exit.It doesn't work yet! Your guide is incomplete (yet) ;)

Comment: Yeah this does not work.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: @SorinSbarnea those ips are private and never go over the internet, so I don't know what you mean by "safest". You'll have best luck if they aren't the same IP range as the cafe, or workplace from which you are connecting. Try 192.168.42.* :)

Comment: PPTP does rely in ip protocol GRE. Some ISPs block this. If this is the case, a different solution is needed.

Answer (score 85):

> WARNING: PPTP IS AN INSECURE PROTOCOL!  Not only has the encryption been breached, but it sends your authentication in clear text and is easily intercepted. It has been estimated that the amount of time required to brute-force the password is roughly equivalent to the time required to brute-force a single DES key. Consider using OpenVPN or another VPN architecture instead of PPTP!

I used [this guide](http://silverlinux.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-pptp-vpn-on-ubuntu-1204-pptpd.html) to set up a PPTP VPN server on my Ubuntu 12.04 server.

---

To summarize the main points in the link, though:

1: Install `pptpd` and `ufw`.  `iptables` can be used in place of ufw, but for the sake of easiness, `ufw` is better if you don't know `iptables`.
`sudo apt-get install pptpd ufw`

2: Open the ports needed.  The guide suggests 22 (SSH) and 1723 for the pptp vpn.

```
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw allow 1723
sudo ufw enable
```

3: Edit `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options`.  Open the file with your favorite editor (mine's nano, so the command for me is `sudo nano /etc/ppp/pptpd-options`), and comment out these lines by putting a `#` before them, if you want this to work universally on all OSes:

```
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
```

You can comment this line if you want to disable encryption: `require-mppe-128`

4: While editing `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options`, add DNS servers for the VPN.  This example uses OpenDNS servers:

```
ms-dns 208.67.222.222
ms-dns 208.67.220.220
```

5: Edit `/etc/pptpd.conf`.  Open the file with your favorite editor (mine's nano, so the command for me is `sudo nano /etc/pptpd.conf`).  You need to add the local VPN IPs for the system, so add:

```
localip 10.99.99.99
remoteip 10.99.99.100-199
```

If your system is a VPS, use the public IP for "localip".  If it is not and is on a local network, use your computer's network IP.  Use different IPs and ranges if these IPs exist on your subnet!
If you don't know your public IP of your VPS, find it by running `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`

6: Edit `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`.  Open the file with your favorite editor (mine's nano, so the command for me is `sudo nano /etc/ppp/chap-secrets`), and add the auth data.
The format for `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` is:

```
[Username] [Service] [Password] [Allowed IP Address]
```

An example would be:  `sampleuser pptpd samplepassword *`

7: Restart pptpd.  Run this command in terminal: `sudo /etc/init.d/pptpd restart`

8: Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`.  Open the file with your favorite editor (mine's nano, so the command for me is `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`).  Un-comment the following line (by removing the `#` at the beginning of it) in `/etc/sysctl.conf`: `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
Reload the configuration:  `sudo sysctl -p`

9: **This step assumes you have ufw.**
Edit `/etc/default/ufw` and change the option `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY` from `DROP` to `ACCEPT`

10: **This step assumes you have ufw.**
Edit `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, and add the following either at the beginning of `/etc/ufw/before.rules` or just before the `*filter` rules (recommended):

```
# NAT table rules
*nat

:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow forward traffic to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.99.99.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# Process the NAT table rules
COMMIT
```

If you have kernel version 3.18 and newer (you can check this by running `uname -r`), also add the following lines before the `# drop INVALID packets ...` line:

```
-A ufw-before-input -p 47 -j ACCEPT
```

11:  Restart the firewall, to refresh the rule sets and to apply the rules we added to the `/etc/ufw/*.rules` files:  `sudo ufw disable && sudo ufw enable`

**Warning:** If you have other ports you need open, such as for HTTPS if your server hosts a website, you need to individually add those ports to the allowed list with `sudo ufw allow <PORT>`

Comment: Now what the heck do I do :D I've got that working on the server, no idea how to connect to it lol

Comment: @Jamie There's a ton of other documents and entries here on Ask Ubuntu on connecting to a VPN not to mention documentation inside Network Manager.  This question only covers setting up the VPN, and the server side.  NOT the connecting to it part.

Comment: :D super fast response :D I think I may have worked it out, I must have just set something incorrectly. This said ufw is active and allowing most ports. I will play with iptables see if this gets me anyway

Comment: @Jamie I can give you iptables commands to use when I get home of you prefer iptables to ufw.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas thats very nice of you. Although I do worry that I really am just closing my eyes and hoping this works :) I have already installed ufw, and now am running both. Although I don't think this should be a problem. If you believe that adding the commands for iptables then I'm a very eager and happy to try these out.

Comment: @Jamie the iptables rules are the ones I use I'll have to dig them up though.

Comment: Wonder if its worth removing ufw. Although from using ufw, its super clean. I am rather liking this firewall. Having 2 installed seems overkill :D

Comment: iptables/netfilter is used with ufw, ufw is just nicer with rules and commands handling for the end users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15503/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-thomas-w).

Comment: Hi again @thomas Just a random quick one, is there any reason why this would have closed access to port 443, I can't see it in the `ufw status` anymore and all https requests are timing out, opps.

Comment: @Jamie 'sudo ufw allow 443', 'sudo ufw allow 80' (HTTPS and HTTP respectively).  ufw will lock ports unless you tell it which ones you want.  (you should just ping me in chat next time btw)

Comment: I did all this, started the service, but then `ifconfig` only shows `etho` and `lo`.  What's wrong?

Comment: Wonderful.  Worked the first time.  You can login to your VPN through Windows 7 by going to `connect to a network` and typing your site's public IP address.  Use the username and password you specified.  It can time out without disconnecting; so, if your internet seems to be disconnected, disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: Please, remove the `sudo ifw disable`. It is bad advice. If the firewall goes down even for a split second, it is open to hackers to enjoy attacking your server. You may just do `sudo ifw reload` assuming it is already enabled (which it should be.)

Comment: @AlexisWilke That was suggested in the *source* where I got the information.  I agree, turning the firewall off is bad, but in this case you ***will not apply the IPv4 forwarding rules that were added to the `ufw` rule configuration files*** without restarting the `ufw` firewall.  In this case, it is a necessity, not an optional step.

Comment: @ThomasW. what do if my local IP in 10.10.10.0/24 range and remote IP in 192.168.0.0/24 range?

Comment: @Lnux I don't understand the question?

Comment: @ThomasW. Can i set `localip 10.10.10.50
remoteip 192.168.0.1-100` in `/etc/pptpd.conf` file ?

Comment: @Lnux I believe localip and remoteip have to be in the same subnet, so I don't think so... you are free to test though if you wish

Comment: @ThomasW.. You're right. local ip and remote ip should be in same subnet. still i am confused about dhcp. Do i need to configure dhcp to assign ip or it will be automatically assign by  defining ip range with remoteip in `/etc/pptpd.conf`?

Comment: I tried all the solutions (including the accepted answer) and this is the only solution that full worked. It is working on my computer (windows 7), now to figure out the part on how to connect to my android mobile phone

Answer (score 18):

### PPTP VPN on Ubuntu 12.04 Example

Here is a quick tutorial to set up a basic PPTP VPN server on Ubuntu 12.04.

> Install Necessary Packages

```
                          sudo apt-get install ppp pptpd
```

> Configure PPTP IP Ranges on the Server

```
                          sudo nano /etc/pptpd.conf
```

Add the following lines in end

```
                          localip 10.89.64.1
                          remoteip 10.89.64.100-150
```

This sets up the PPTP server to use IP 10.89.64.1 while distributing the IP range 10.89.64.100 to 10.89.64.150 to PPTP clients. Change these as you wish as long as they are private IP addresses and do not conflict with IP addresses already used by your server.

> Configure DNS Servers to Use When Clients Connect to this PPTP Server

```
                          sudo nano /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
```

Modify **OR** Add the following lines in end

```
                          ms-dns 8.8.8.8
                          ms-dns 8.8.4.4
```

> Create a PPTP User

```
                          sudo nano /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
```

> Append a line at the bottom so your file looks something like:

```
                          # client    server  secret          IP addresses
                          test        pptpd   abcd1234        *
```

> Configure NAT for PPTP Connections

Without this step you will be able to connect but your connection will not be able to load any web connection from this server.

```
                          sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following to the bottom right before “exit 0” line:

```
                          iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Assuming eth0, you can use `ifconfig` to check network name.

> Enable IPv4 forwading:

```
                          sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

> Uncomment the following line:

```
                          net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

> Then reload the configuration:

```
                          sudo sysctl -p
```

> Reboot your VPS and everything should work swimmingly from any PPTP client.

---

> Client side configuration

For Mac, make sure you added PPTP VPN connection. Besides that you only need to setup server address, account name, and password in authentication settings. No pain here.

For Linux, NetworkManager to add VPN connections. Make sure you added PPTP VPN connection. And the configuration I use is here:

[How To Debug and Fix PPTP/VPN Client Connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294120/how-to-debug-and-fix-pptp-vpn-client-connection/295309#295309)

[image]

> And for Windows

[image]

Comment: Does this method also work on Ubuntu 12.04 non-server edition? What IP number the client has to use to connect to this VPN network?

Comment: Yes it is for non-server edition also, You have to use server ip on client to connect to vpn @Rasoul

Comment: Doesn't work, Ubuntu server 13.04. Client stuck looking for DNS.

Comment: @knutole check that your IPTables rules are routing properly. Make sure you have the en0 interface and it's not named something else. You should see a public IP address listed.

Comment: ok, so, in your example which ip is server ip? 10.89.64.1 ? Then in the Ubuntu network manager the client would list 10.89.64.1 as the Gateway?

Comment: @dranxo No the server ip is public ip, when you connect with server ip, you will have 10. series ip. i hope you understand.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers on this thread were only partial answers in my case. Here's what worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.3

```
sudo apt-get install pptpd
```

Append the following to /etc/pptpd.conf (IP Address does not matter, this is only IP Addresses for your ppp0 interface.)

```
localip 10.0.0.1
remoteip 10.0.0.100-200
```

Add DNS Servers to /etc/ppp/pptpd-options

```
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
```

### Enable IP Forwarding

```
sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Uncomment this line

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Save changes

```
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Edit /etc/ppp/chap-secrets, add a VPN user in this format:

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client    server  secret          IP addresses
username pptpd supersecretpassword *
```

Restart PPTP

```
service pptpd restart
```

Run `ifconfig`and find your default interface, in my case it was *br0* (I changed it to allow virtual machines on my physical machine to share the interface. Yours will probably be *en0*)

[image]

Back up iptables

```
iptables-save > ~/iptables.save
```

Now make your iptables changes use your default interface as revealed by ifconfig.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -i ppp0 -j ACCEPT
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface br0 -j ACCEPT
```

To keep it persistent when your system reboots;

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

## Add VPN on client computer (Mac)

System Preferences > Network > [+] > VPN

[image]

[image]

Then choose Authentication settings > Password, then fill in your password here

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here's a pretty sweet project that scripts away the OpenVPN pain:

https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

Just run it and it will install open vpn and configure it.  At the end it will pop out a client.ovpn file that you can use to setup you client.  Seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Holy cow. It just works. I wonder why it doesn't have widespread recognition.