# PPTP VPN on Ubuntu Server 12.10 fails to connect, with error: no ifupdown configuration found

Tags: vpn, pptp

I am trying to setup a PPTP VPN server on Ubuntu Server 12.10. I had a few errors and by observing the logs, I managed to solve them.

Now, I get this error, and it seems I am not able to find a solution to it.

Here is the out put of `tail -n 30 /var/log/syslog | grep -i ppp`:

```
Jan  7 22:55:17 MyServer pptpd[32719]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Jan  7 22:55:17 MyServer pptpd[32720]: CTRL (PPPD Launcher): program binary = /usr/sbin/pppd
Jan  7 22:55:17 MyServer pptpd[32720]: CTRL (PPPD Launcher): local address = 192.168.0.1
Jan  7 22:55:17 MyServer pptpd[32720]: CTRL (PPPD Launcher): remote address = 192.168.0.234
Jan  7 22:55:17 MyServer pppd[32720]: Plugin /usr/lib/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Jan  7 22:55:17 MyServer pppd[32720]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jan  7 22:55:17 MyServer pppd[32720]: Using interface ppp0
Jan  7 22:55:17 MyServer pppd[32720]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
Jan  7 22:55:17 MyServer NetworkManager[1122]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jan  7 22:55:17 MyServer NetworkManager[1122]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jan  7 22:55:46 MyServer pptpd[32719]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[32720]
Jan  7 22:55:46 MyServer pppd[32720]: Hangup (SIGHUP)
Jan  7 22:55:46 MyServer pppd[32720]: Modem hangup
Jan  7 22:55:46 MyServer pppd[32720]: Connection terminated.
Jan  7 22:55:46 MyServer NetworkManager[1122]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jan  7 22:55:46 MyServer pppd[32720]: Exit.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit**
As I said my server is Ubuntu Server 12.10. Client is Kubuntu 12.10.
I have successfully set up a PPTP VPN server on CentOS 6, but I failed to do so on Ubuntu.

Comment: I have the same problem when connecting to a Synology DS VPN Server which uses PPTP. Ubuntu 12.10 refuses to connect with the same error whereas it was working on Ubuntu 12.04...

Comment: I have the same problem on Linux Mint 14, which is based on Ubuntu 12.10.  Has anyone found the solution to this please?

Comment: Please have a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/easiest-way-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-vpn-server/306470#306470

Answer (score -1):

I can see this is probably a dead topic by now. But, if you are using ubuntu server, most people run into problems using Network Manager and forwarding. You can uninstall this and only leave your eth0 in the adapter list (/etc/network/interfaces). PPTP will manage the up/down events for you. I found [pptpd-ubuntu-12-04-vps-fail2ban](http://globalcynic.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/pptpd-ubuntu-12-04-vps-fail2ban/) to be the best guide I have seen so far and it has some troubleshooting steps.