# Trying to connection to a windows VPN

Tags: networking, windows, vpn

I'm new to VPNs in general and I'd firgue learning how to do this on ubuntu would be a great start I'm using pptd from the network manager. Whenever I try and connect to the vpn that's using Window's Server, I get "authenication required" and it doesn't connect. Under the PPTP Advanced Options I have MSCHAP MSCHAPV2 checked as well as MPPE, and under security I have 128-bit slected. To get more information I checked the sys log and here is the information my system returning when I try and connect.

```
May 27 15:49:29 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
May 27 15:49:29 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 7139
May 27 15:49:29 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
May 27 15:49:29 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
May 27 15:49:29 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <info> VPN connection 'Help Desk' (Connect) reply received.
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu pppd[7143]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu pppd[7143]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu pppd[7143]: Using interface ppp0
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu pppd[7143]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu pptp[7146]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
May 27 15:49:30 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 60546).
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:950]: PPTP_SET_LINK_INFO received from peer_callid 0
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:953]:   send_accm is 00000000, recv_accm is FFFFFFFF
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 warn[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:956]: Non-zero Async Control Character Maps are not supported!
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pppd[7143]: MS-CHAP authentication failed: E=649 No dialin permission
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pppd[7143]: CHAP authentication failed
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:950]: PPTP_SET_LINK_INFO received from peer_callid 0
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:953]:   send_accm is FFFFFFFF, recv_accm is FFFFFFFF
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 warn[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:956]: Non-zero Async Control Character Maps are not supported!
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pppd[7143]: Connection terminated.
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu avahi-daemon[668]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7146]: nm-pptp-service-7139 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7146]: nm-pptp-service-7139 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pptp[7154]: nm-pptp-service-7139 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu pppd[7143]: Exit.
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
May 27 15:49:31 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
May 27 15:49:37 austin-ubuntu NetworkManager[973]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is kinda unrelated, but a really good/free/easy VPN solution is hamachi at www.logmein.com. there is even a front end for ubuntu called haguichi with a ppa at www.webupd8.org Sometimes you just want it working now.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/294120/how-to-debug-and-fix-pptp-vpn-client-connection/295309#295309

Comment: Sadly it's not a duplicate the sys logs are different and with this question he/she had their ip address/password entered incorrectly. I no that mine aren't

Answer (score 3):

I tracked down my problem. It lied with the line

```
MS-CHAP authentication failed: E=649 No dialin permission
```

I talked to my sys-admin and it turns out I didn't have the correct permissions to connect to the vpn on windows server side. There goes a couple of hours thinking something was wrong on my end when it wasn't

Comment: I found additional [documented error codes](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml), which were also very helpful.