# 13.04 PPTP VNP to Windows Server but NO Internet

Tags: networking, 13.04, windows, vpn, pptp

I am currently running on an Ubuntu 13.04 environment.

I am able to connect just fine to my Office VPN, the only problem I am having now is I don't have internet access once I am connected.  There is a little lock symbol next to the internet connection symbol in the top right hand corner by my clock.

I know when I was on a windows machine I was able to VPN and piggie back off the office IP address just fine.  Is there a setting I need to change on my Ubuntu machine to do the same?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/294120/how-to-debug-and-fix-pptp-vpn-client-connection/295309#295309

Comment: Thanks, these are the exact settings I am using to successfully VPN into my office network.  However, I cannot access internet once I do.

Answer (score 0):

The option you're looking for is "Use remote gateway for all traffic", although I'm not sure which VPN solution you're using, so I can't give you any more detail.

It's just a configuration options not a software/OS problem.  Strike that...

You appear to be referring to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/330833).

Comment: I setup my VPN using this method.  http://askubuntu.com/a/295309/168674