# ubuntu 14.04 VPN: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect with vpn to work I get the following:

```
Jun 11 17:48:11 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <info> Starting VPN service 'vpnc'...
Jun 11 17:48:11 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc), PID 21051
Jun 11 17:48:11 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' appeared; activating connections
Jun 11 17:48:11 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Jun 11 17:48:11 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN connection 'someconnection' (Connect) reply received.
Jun 11 17:48:11 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Jun 11 17:48:11 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jun 11 17:48:11 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Jun 11 17:48:14 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Jun 11 17:48:14 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Jun 11 17:48:14 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Jun 11 17:48:14 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Jun 11 17:48:14 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <info> Policy set 'somewifi' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Jun 11 17:48:14 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Jun 11 17:48:19 MYLAPTOP NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' disappeared
```

using cisco compatible vpnc on ubuntu 14.04

tried also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294120/how-to-debug-and-fix-pptp-vpn-client-connection) (not same vpn client but tried it) did not help... please help...

and after running

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-vpnc-service --debug
```

for debugging i see:

```
.
.
.
S5.5 do xauth reply
 [2015-06-11 18:15:28]


---!!!!!!!!! entering phase2_fatal !!!!!!!!!---
.
.
.


   PARSING PAYLOAD type: 00 (ISAKMP_PAYLOAD_NONE)
   PARSE_OK
/usr/sbin/vpnc: noninteractive can't reuse password
** (nm-vpnc-service:21916): WARNING **: vpnc exited with error code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This usually means you typed the wrong password (either the user password or the group password).

The hint is the last line of the debug log:

```
/usr/sbin/vpnc: noninteractive can't reuse password
```

Since you configured the vpn through network manager, the `vpnc` command is invoked non-interactively and it can't ask for a new password once it detects the one you supplied is wrong (hence the "*can't reuse password*" message).

To actually find this out, you might want to check within the first blocks of the debug, where you will be able to see the:

```
Config: Debug 3
Config: Script /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-vpnc-service-vpnc-helper
Config: Cisco UDP Encapsulation Port 0
Config: Local Port 0
Config: IKE DH Group dh2
Config: Perfect Forward Secrecy server
Config: IPSec ID MY-VPN
Config: IPSec gateway AA.BB.CC.DD
Config: Xauth username USER
Config: Vendor cisco
Config: Enable Single DES
Config: NAT Traversal Mode natt
Config: Xauth password PASSWORD
Config: IPSec secret SECRET
```

The last two lines contains the plaintext user password and the group shared secret.

I had the same problem and the first google hit was https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2009-June/msg00034.html, since the second one was this question and I was indeed using ubuntu 14.04, I thought it might help here.