# VPN PPTP in ubuntu 16.04 not working?

Tags: 16.04, vpn, pptp

I fill up the details as in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/295309/2413) answer. But when I try to connect, I get:

```
VPN Connection Failed '...because the VPN service stopped'
```

error message on the top right corner of the screen:
[image]

running

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

gives me this:

```
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: ** Message: pppd started with pid 8330
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: <info>  [1489091660.9205] vpn-connection[0x1e067e0,54552dfa-6db2-4050-8b47-fd108b79f201,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Mar  9 21:34:20 me pppd[8330]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (plugin_init): initializing
Mar  9 21:34:20 me pppd[8330]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 3 / phase 'serial connection'
Mar  9 21:34:20 me pppd[8330]: Using interface ppp0
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: Using interface ppp0
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/19
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 5 / phase 'establish'
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
Mar  9 21:34:20 me pppd[8330]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/19
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: <info>  [1489091660.9369] manager: (ppp0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Mar  9 21:34:20 me pptp[8335]: nm-pptp-service-8312 log[main:pptp.c:350]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: <info>  [1489091660.9505] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Mar  9 21:34:20 me NetworkManager[6063]: <info>  [1489091660.9506] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar  9 21:34:20 me pptp[8347]: nm-pptp-service-8312 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:259]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Mar  9 21:34:20 me pptp[8347]: nm-pptp-service-8312 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:781]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Mar  9 21:34:20 me pptp[8347]: nm-pptp-service-8312 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:815]: Client connection established.
Mar  9 21:34:21 me pptp[8347]: nm-pptp-service-8312 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:259]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Mar  9 21:34:21 me pptp[8347]: nm-pptp-service-8312 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:900]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Mar  9 21:34:21 me pptp[8347]: nm-pptp-service-8312 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:939]: Outgoing call established (call ID 34527, peer's call ID 32815).
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pppd[8330]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 11 / phase 'disconnect'
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: Connection terminated.
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pppd[8330]: Connection terminated.
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: ** Message: Terminated ppp daemon with PID 8330.
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: <warn>  [1489091691.9659] vpn-connection[0x1e067e0,54552dfa-6db2-4050-8b47-fd108b79f201,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: <info>  [1489091691.9661] vpn-connection[0x1e067e0,54552dfa-6db2-4050-8b47-fd108b79f201,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: <error> [1489091691.9681] platform-linux: do-change-link[13]: failure changing link: failure 19 (No such device)
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: <warn>  [1489091691.9682] device (ppp0): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: <info>  [1489091691.9693] vpn-connection[0x1e067e0,54552dfa-6db2-4050-8b47-fd108b79f201,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: <info>  [1489091691.9710] vpn-connection[0x1e067e0,54552dfa-6db2-4050-8b47-fd108b79f201,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: state change reason: unknown (0)
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: <info>  [1489091691.9719] vpn-connection[0x1e067e0,54552dfa-6db2-4050-8b47-fd108b79f201,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN service disappeared
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: <info>  [1489091691.9727] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 1 / phase 'dead'
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: Terminating on signal 15
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp 217.145.41.15 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-8312 (pid 8333) terminated with signal 15
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: Modem hangup
Mar  9 21:34:51 me NetworkManager[6063]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_exit_notify): cleaning up
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pptp[8335]: nm-pptp-service-8312 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:220]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pptp[8335]: nm-pptp-service-8312 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:232]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pppd[8330]: Terminating on signal 15
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pppd[8330]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp 217.145.41.15 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-8312 (pid 8333) terminated with signal 15
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pppd[8330]: Modem hangup
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pptp[8347]: nm-pptp-service-8312 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:245]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pptp[8347]: nm-pptp-service-8312 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:259]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pptp[8347]: nm-pptp-service-8312 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:84]: Closing connection (call state)
Mar  9 21:34:51 me pppd[8330]: Exit.
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure pptp VPN server and client from the terminal using these steps:

### VPN Server Setup:

Install and update the VPN server and client packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pptpd ppp pptp-linux
```

**Four files has to be configured for the server:**

- /etc/pptpd.conf
- /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
- /etc/ppp/options
- /etc/chat-secrets)

**/etc/pptpd.conf:**

```
option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
logwtmp
localip 192.168.23.20
remoteip 192.168.23.30-39
```

**/etc/ppp/pptpd-options:**

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
noipx ## you don’t need IPX
mtu 1490 ## may help your linux client from disconnecting
mru 1490 ## may help your linux client from disconnecting
```

**/etc/ppp/options:**

```
lock
```

**/etc/ppp/chap-secrets:**

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client    server  secret  IP addresses

[username]  pptpd [userpass] *
```

(The [username] and [userpass] are entries without the brackets.)

**Now restart the server with:**

```
$ sudo service pptpd restart
```

### VPN Client Setup:

**Four configuration files are involved:**

- /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn
- /etc/ppp/options.pptp
- /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
- /etc/ppp/ip-up.local

**/etc/ppp/peers/myvpn:**

```
# replace the bracket paramters with the host name of the VPN server and VPN user
remotename myvpn
linkname myvpn
ipparam myvpn
pty "pptp [vpn server] --nolaunchpppd "
name [username]
usepeerdns
require-mppe
refuse-eap
noauth

# adopt defaults from the pptp-linux package
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
```

**/etc/ppp/options.pptp:**

```
lock
noauth
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
```

**/etc/ppp/chap-secrets:**

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client    server  secret  IP addresses
username myvpn password *
```

**/etc/ppp/ip-up.local:**

```
#!/bin/sh
network=`echo $IPREMOTE | awk -F\. '{print $1"."$2"."$3".0/24"}'`
route add -net $network $IFNAME
```

**Connect the VPN client with:**

```
$ sudo pon myvpn
```

**End the VPN connection with:**

```
$ sudo poff myvpn
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem was caused by my ISP not giving me a public IP by default, so I could solve it without recourse to your solution.

Comment: on my system there is file /etc/ppp/ip-up and directory /etc/ppp/ip-up.d - Should ip-up.local still be separate file?

Comment: It's not necessary to have an ip-up.local.  but if one exists it will be executed.  It's a way to leave the default files the say they are and add something special to be executed.

Comment: I don't need to install vpn server, just want to connect a vpn server use pptp.  Did not work follow your steps.

Comment: What do you get when you telnet to the server's vpn port; `telnet server 1723`?

Comment: what is remote ip?

Comment: The IP of your computer is local.  Any other IP is remote to you.  If you connect to a computer there are two IP's involved.  The IP  (local) of the machine you are using and the IP (remote) of the machine you are connected to.

Comment: @L.D.James I modify your solution, and that works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Modified from @L.D.James solution

Ubuntu 16.04

### VPN Client Setup:

**Four configuration files are involved:**

- /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn
- /etc/ppp/options.pptp
- /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
- /etc/ppp/ip-up.local

**/etc/ppp/peers/myvpn:**

```
# replace the bracket paramters with the host name of the VPN server and VPN user
remotename myvpn
linkname myvpn
ipparam myvpn
pty "pptp 1.2.3.4 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0"
lock
nodeflate
name LoginName 
usepeerdns
require-mppe
noauth
require-mppe-128
```

1. Change **1.2.3.4** to your VPN Host IP Address. and
2. Change **LoginName** to your login name

**/etc/ppp/options.pptp:**

```
lock
noauth
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
name LoginName
require-mppe-128
ipparam myvpn
```

3. Change **LoginName** to your login name

**/etc/ppp/chap-secrets:**

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client    server  secret  IP addresses
LoginName myvpn LoginPassword *
```

4. Change **LoginName** to your login name
5. Change **LoginPassword** to your login password

**/etc/ppp/ip-up.local:**

```
#!/bin/sh
network=`echo $IPREMOTE | awk -F\. '{print $1"."$2"."$3".0/24"}'`
route add -net $network $IFNAME
```

**Start the VPN client with:**

```
$ sudo pon vicomvpn dump logfd 2 nodetach
pppd options in effect:
nodetach        # (from command line)
logfd 2     # (from command line)
linkname myvpn      # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn)
dump        # (from command line)
noauth      # (from /etc/ppp/peers/vicomvpn)
name LoginName      # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn)
remotename myvpn        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn)
        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn)
pty pptp 1.2.3.4 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn)
crtscts     # (from /etc/ppp/options)
        # (from /etc/ppp/options)
asyncmap 0      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-failure 4      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-interval 30        # (from /etc/ppp/options)
hide-password       # (from /etc/ppp/options)
ipparam myvpn       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn)
usepeerdns      # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn)
nodeflate       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn)
require-mppe        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn)
require-mppe-128        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn)
noipx       # (from /etc/ppp/options)
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/22
CHAP authentication succeeded
MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
local  IP address 192.168.1.142
remote IP address 192.168.1.1
primary   DNS address 19.168.1.1
```

**End the VPN connection with:**

```
$ sudo poff myvpn
```

Reference : [MS-CHAP[v2] auth, Microsoft VPN client setup with pptpclient](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=120781)