# How to use a VPN which was created on Ubuntu machine?

Tags: vpn, pptp

I followed these instructions:
https://askubuntu.com/a/305401

How can I connect to my VPN server? What's the ip address I need to connect to? I want to do that from my mobile phone.

```
###############################################################################
# $Id$
#
# Sample Poptop configuration file /etc/pptpd.conf
#
# Changes are effective when pptpd is restarted.
###############################################################################

# TAG: ppp
#   Path to the pppd program, default '/usr/sbin/pppd' on Linux
#
#ppp /usr/sbin/pppd

# TAG: option
#   Specifies the location of the PPP options file.
#   By default PPP looks in '/etc/ppp/options'
#
option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options

# TAG: debug
#   Turns on (more) debugging to syslog
#
#debug

# TAG: stimeout
#   Specifies timeout (in seconds) on starting ctrl connection
#
# stimeout 10

# TAG: noipparam
#       Suppress the passing of the client's IP address to PPP, which is
#       done by default otherwise.
#
#noipparam

# TAG: logwtmp
#   Use wtmp(5) to record client connections and disconnections.
#
logwtmp

# TAG: bcrelay <if>
#   Turns on broadcast relay to clients from interface <if>
#
#bcrelay eth1

# TAG: localip
# TAG: remoteip
#   Specifies the local and remote IP address ranges.
#
#       Any addresses work as long as the local machine takes care of the
#       routing.  But if you want to use MS-Windows networking, you should
#       use IP addresses out of the LAN address space and use the proxyarp
#       option in the pppd options file, or run bcrelay.
#
#   You can specify single IP addresses seperated by commas or you can
#   specify ranges, or both. For example:
#
#       192.168.0.234,192.168.0.245-249,192.168.0.254
#
#   IMPORTANT RESTRICTIONS:
#
#   1. No spaces are permitted between commas or within addresses.
#
#   2. If you give more IP addresses than MAX_CONNECTIONS, it will
#      start at the beginning of the list and go until it gets 
#      MAX_CONNECTIONS IPs. Others will be ignored.
#
#   3. No shortcuts in ranges! ie. 234-8 does not mean 234 to 238,
#      you must type 234-238 if you mean this.
#
#   4. If you give a single localIP, that's ok - all local IPs will
#      be set to the given one. You MUST still give at least one remote
#      IP for each simultaneous client.
#
# (Recommended)
#localip 192.168.0.1
#remoteip 192.168.0.234-238,192.168.0.245
# or
#localip 192.168.0.234-238,192.168.0.245
#remoteip 192.168.1.234-238,192.168.1.245

localip 10.99.99.99
remoteip 10.99.99.100-199
```

Ifconfig:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:15:2d:d1:ce:a6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.121  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3783462 errors:108 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:5067689
          TX packets:2485445 errors:14 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:423273032 (423.2 MB)  TX bytes:413521637 (413.5 MB)
          Interrupt:17
```

Comment: @Braiam: Done. Why do you need ifconfig?

Comment: `ifconfig` output seems to not be here.  We need the output to get the IP address assigned to your system.  If the IP is an actual public IP address and not a private network IP address (like behind a router) then you can connect to that.  Otherwise, we need you to find out the public IP address and maybe do some port forwarding :/

Comment: @Braiam done!..

Comment: Router I am pretty sure. @Braiam

Comment: Will your cellphone get a range of ip's that you know of?

Comment: I don't know, sorry