# Error message "access denied" setting up VPN

Tags: encryption, vpn

I am new to Linux and I am trying to learn as much as possible. I have installed Ubuntu 13.0.4 and selected basic server, I am now trying to setup VPN to access my files from anywhere.  However getting errors when disabling encryption. The steps I am following is below from one of the member here:

- [Easiest way to setup Ubuntu as a VPN server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/easiest-way-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-vpn-server)

I am getting errors on doing the steps below:

```
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
```

Error message: `access denied`, even though I am logged on as root.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Which instructions? Can you add a link to them and can you let us know at what point it goes wrong together with what error message you get

Comment: @Braiam Comment those lines, not add

Comment: And Radu beat me to explaining this in an answer. :P  But yes, as Radu says, there are no commands to run.  You need to edit `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options` as root (`sudo nano /etc/ppp/pptpd-options` or replace `nano` with your favorite command line text editor) and comment out all three of those lines with a `#` character at the beginning.  I have edited my answer on the guide/link you're using to expand on how to edit a file on the command line... (sorta).

Answer (score 1):

These are no commands to execute them in terminal. At the step 3 it says clear:

> 3: Edit `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options`. Comment out these lines, if you want this to work universally on all OSes:
>
> ```
> refuse-pap
> refuse-chap
> refuse-mschap
> ```
>
> You can comment this line if you want to disable encryption: `require-mppe-128`

So, open `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options` file with root privileges, using the following command:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
```

and comment those lines by adding a hash (`#`) character in front of each one. When you finish, save the file and clse it.

Comment: Or, use nano, if you're working with a remote server and don't have a GUI.  I put instructions to use nano, because I always am working on this stuff remotely and can't X-forward.

Comment: Thanks for making it all very clear to me i will go ahead and and edit

Comment: Thanks Radu i manged to do that all good now.  How ever i am now step 10 were i have to edit the ufw 10: This step assumes you have UFW. Edit /etc/ufw/before.rules, and add the following either at the beginning of /etc/ufw/before.rules or just before the *filter rules (recommended).  when the nano editor opened the page was blank i was suprised to see blank screen i still proceeded to enter the details.  i am i in the right track here?

Comment: @user195992 Where you wish - I will choose recommended...  If this answered your question, you may [mark this answer as accepted](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers), by clicking the green check mark next to it. That will indicate that your problem is solved.