# ufw before.rules file blank, does this impact setting up VPN server?

Tags: ufw

Hi all please assit i am trying to setup `open-vpn` following this link and currently having some issues.

[Easiest way to setup Ubuntu as a VPN server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/easiest-way-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-vpn-server)

step 10 where I have to edit the ufw 10: This step assumes you have UFW. `Edit /etc/ufw/before.rules, and add the following either at the beginning of /etc/ufw/before.rules or just before the *filter rules (recommended)`. when the `nano` editor opened the page was blank i was surprised to see blank screen I still proceeded to enter the details. Not sure if i am in the right track here?.

Answer (score 2):

If you'll reread that step in my answer to that question, you'll  notice it says **"add the following either at the beginning of /etc/ufw/before.rules"** in that step.  It also says after that "or just before the *filter rules".

Since there are no rules, follow the first part of that step, and just put the rules into that file, right at the beginning of the file, whether it's blank or not.  That should then work.  (Note, I had to tweak the rules for my iptables setup, since I don't use ufw, however, you can just add the rules to the file ***like that step says in that guide*** and then save the file)