# Can I use Ubuntu Server to replace our Windows environment?

Tags: vpn, ms-exchange, domain-server

I have recently been put in charge of a network overhaul for our company. I have done plenty with Ubuntu in school but it has been a few years. I would like to replace our current servers with Ubuntu, although I am unaware if it will work. Our current environment runs a Domain, Exchange, and VPN. I know there are solutions capable for this. I guess my man worry is will windows 7 and windows XP be able to use Ubuntu as a Domain Controller?

If anyone has had success with this I would love some input. I have a meeting in a couple months that I am suppose to explain our plan.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely Ubuntu can replace your Windows environment. Let me put this as short answer. Your requirements and their alternative: (Domain, Exchange, and VPN).

**Domain Controler**

As a domain controller, You can use [Samba4](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba)

Follow this tutorial you can setup a samba4 domain controller in short time :  [Samba4 Domain Controller on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS](http://paulcolfer.ie/os/linux/samba-4-domain-controller-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/)

If you prefer video tutorials check out : [Samba4 as domain controller](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=samba4%20as%20domain%20controller)

**Exchange Server**

Switching from Microsoft Exchange may be a bit tricky, But there are a good alternatives. Checkout:

[Citadel](http://www.citadel.org/), [open-xchange](http://www.open-xchange.com/home.html),  [Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.org/2013/10/zentyal-launches-the-only-native-microsoft-exchange-replacement/)
 and [How to Install & configure Zentyal](http://laboratory.zentyal.org/install-configure-zentyals-technology-preview-of-native-ms-exchange-replacement/)

Even you can checkout my favorite awesome new project [mailpile](http://www.mailpile.is/) It's not ready for production but you will find it very interesting.

**Ubuntu as a VPN server**

Checkout: [Easiest way to setup Ubuntu as a VPN server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/easiest-way-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-vpn-server)