# How do I setup a VPN server on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with No-IP?

Tags: networking, vpn

All the installation guides for VPN servers I can find go into huge detail about how to setup an IP address range (e.g. [Easiest way to setup Ubuntu as a VPN server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/easiest-way-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-vpn-server)). If I'm using [No-IP](https://www.noip.com) to give my PC an IP address is there a simple way to setup a VPN server?

Comment: Depending on the "huge detail about IP addresses" (internal or external?), the answer may be "Yes" or "maybe".  Could you give a link to the actual documentation you're talking about and what version of Ubuntu you're running??? :P  ;-)

Comment: Added the version and a link to the kind of documentation I've seen.

Comment: If you use [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/305401/344926): yes!

Comment: But the answers to that question don't specify why you have to change the default PPTP behavior from 'delegate' to 'remoteip'. If I'm using No-IP can I leave it? If not, what remoteip range do I need to use, if any?