# How can I use Ubuntu server 14.04 to remotely access my homenetwork?

Tags: networking, server, vpn

At home I have a server with Ubuntu server 14.04 installed. This homeserver is mainly used for backups and storage of family files within the network (for this I use owncloud).

I want to gain access to my homeserver outside of my home network. At first I just opened up port 80 on my router and I could enter my homeserver. I stopped doing this because I want more security.

So I was looking for alternatives. A friend told me to use VPN.

My questions:

1. How should I access my homeserver from a remote location, if I need maximum security?
2. Is it possible to gain access to my home network (in the
   Netherlands) while I am abroad (for example in America) so I could
   enjoy watching streams which are only available in The Netherlands?

Comment: For a start, use a different port, that is less likely to be guessed. Second, VPN is what you want, maybe http://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/easiest-way-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-vpn-server will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are your answers:

1. If you need maximum security I suggest to use a VPN. I suggest OpenVPN, you can find details over here: [wiki - VPN](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VPN). If you don't want to use VPN you can still open your router ports to web, please consider changing port numbers (for instance don't use port 80 for http)
2. For 'watching streams which are only available in The Netherlands' you should instead use a proxy (e.g. [squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/squid.html)). For this you must take in account your NL home network bandwith, if it's too slow you won't be able to watch streams fluenty.

Comment: This worked for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bafYav1QuWs

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access your server via command line use ssh. I would suggest to use it with a private key setup.

Another alternative is SoftEther as a kind of successor to OpenVPN. You can find a tutorial [here.](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/A._Examples_of_Building_VPN_Networks)